# "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" PKID Counts as Column even with AUTOINCREMENT?

Tags: mysql, sql

"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

{
code: 'ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW',
errno: 1136,
sqlMessage: "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1",
sqlState: '21S01',
index: 0,
sql: "INSERT IGNORE INTO craig.cdata (pkid,country,region,site,area,category,id,repost_of,last_updated,title,neighborhood,url,lat,lon,address,misc,compensation) VALUES (pkid),('testcountry15'), ('testregion14'), ('testsite13'), ('testarea12'), ('testcategory11'), ('testid10'), ('repostoftest9'), ('lastupdatedtest8'), ('titletest7'), ('neighborhoodtest6'), ('urltest5'), ('lattest4'), ('lontest3'), ('addresstest2'), ('misctest2'), ('compensationtest1');"
}

controller: {"country":"testcountry15","region":"testregion14","site":"testsite13","area":"testarea12","category":"testcategory11","id":"testid10","repost_of":"repostoftest9","last_updated":"lastupdatedtest8","title":"titletest7","neighborhood":"neighborhoodtest6","url":"urltest5","lat":"lattest4","lon":"lontest3","address":"addresstest2","misc":"misctest2","compensation":"compensationtest1"}

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `craig`;
CREATE DATABASE `craig` DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

USE `databasename`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbname.database1;
CREATE TABLE dbname.database1 (
            `pkid`          int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `country`       varchar(200),
            `region`        varchar(200),
            `site`          varchar(200),
            `area`          varchar(200),
            `category`      varchar(200),
            `id`            varchar(200),
            `repost_of`     varchar(200),
            `last_updated`  varchar(200),
            `title`         varchar(200),
            `neighborhood`  varchar(200),
            `url`           varchar(200),
            `lat`           varchar(200),
            `lon`           varchar(200),
            `address`       varchar(200),
            `misc`          varchar(200),
            `compensation`  varchar(200),
            PRIMARY KEY (`pkid`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

let query = `INSERT IGNORE INTO craig.cdata (country,region,site,area,category,id,repost_of,last_updated,title,neighborhood,url,lat,lon,address,misc,compensation) VALUES ('${pg.country}'), ('${pg.region}'), ('${pg.site}'), ('${pg.area}'), ('${pg.category}'), ('${pg.id}'), ('${pg.repost_of}'), ('${pg.last_updated}'), ('${pg.title}'), ('${pg.neighborhood}'), ('${pg.url}'), ('${pg.lat}'), ('${pg.lon}'), ('${pg.address}'), ('${pg.misc}'), ('${pg.compensation}');`

^^^ SQL Statement. I know its not pretty, but its the best I could come up with learning on my own. I understand that the PKID is not included in this SQL statement which is probably producing the error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1", I thought the whole point of having the PK AI NN ID is to increment to the next new id for any piece of data that is altered by the table, in this case INSERT IGNORE. I use this statement for another server which works the exact same way!

I don't think I am missing a comma, but I also might be crazy! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time. If you need any info, I will provide it promptly.

Comment: This way you are adding many rows with one column each. Try `('${pg.country}', '${pg.region}', '${pg.site}'..., '${pg.compensation}')`

Comment: That worked perfectly! I cant believe it was that simple of a fix! I am back on track and continuing on my project. This is my first time using stack overflow, is there a way to let the system know you were the one to answer my question?!

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. You may accept it if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you are adding many rows with one column each.
Try `.. VALUES ('${pg.country}', '${pg.region}', '${pg.site}'..., '${pg.compensation}')`